# How to calculate probabilities with multiple events and a probability for each event?

Tags: probability

My question is best illustrated in poker example:

The game is Texas Hold'em. I won't explain the rules, just the probabilities.

We have KK and our opponent can have AA or 72. KK is worse than AA but better than 72. For the sake of example, let's say our opponent can have these two hands at the following frequencies:

AA | 50% of the time
72 | 50% of the time

P(KK wins vs. AA) = 0.1805
P(KK wins vs. 72) = 0.8685

So how would we calculate the P(KK wins vs. {AA, 72})? My hunch is that we just do:

P(Opp has AA) * P(KK wins vs. AA) + P(Opp has 72) * P(KK wins vs. 72)

(0.50)(0.1805) + (0.50)(0.8685) = 0.5245, which means we win against our opponent roughly 52.45% of the time if he's playing these two hands against us on average.

This looks awfully like the formula for expected value, except the end result is a probability, not a loss or a gain. Seems like if we wanted to express this as a formula it would be something like:

P(X vs. set of hands H) = $\sum_{n=0}^N P($opponent has $H_n$)*$P$($X$ wins against $H_n$) where N = $(|H|-1)$

What property of probabilities allow us to do this?

Comment: This fact is called [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are using is called [Law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):
$$
P(A|B\&C) = P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|C)P(C)
$$
when $B\cap C=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the chain rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29)

Note to the commentator above, who I cannot respond to directly: Bayes's Theorem is how you update the probabilities of your opponents having a specific hand given that a 72 is played differently by your opponents.  That is, The chain rule tells you how likely you are to win the hand given no more betting.  Bayes's Theorem tells you how lile you are to win the hand given that the 72 will fold to your raise more often than AA.